# Two strings are anagrams or not question quitted with code 11 on C++ Clion

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


void LowerCharacters(string& text);
void OutPutEachLetter(string text, int* ptr);
void comparePointers();

int main() {
    string text1, text2; bool isAnagrams = true;
    int *ptr1=NULL, *ptr2=NULL;
    cout<<"Please enter first string ";
    getline(cin,text1);
    cout<<"Please enter second string ";
    getline(cin,text2);
    LowerCharacters(text1);
    LowerCharacters(text2);
    OutPutEachLetter(text1, ptr1);
    OutPutEachLetter(text2, ptr2);
    for(int i =0; i<26;i++) {
        if (ptr1[i] != ptr2[i]) {
            isAnagrams = false;
        }
    }
    if(isAnagrams)
        cout<<"These two strings are anagrams";
    else
        cout<<"These two strings are not anagrams";
    delete []ptr1; delete []ptr2;
    ptr1=NULL; ptr2=NULL;
}

void LowerCharacters(string& text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            text[i]=tolower(text[i]);
        }
    }


void OutPutEachLetter(string text, int* ptr){

    ptr = new int[26];
    *ptr = {0};
    for(int i =0;i<text.length()-1;i++)
    {
        ptr[text[i]-'a']++;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<26;j++){
        if(ptr[j]!=0){
            cout<<ptr[j]<<"\t"<<char(j+'a')<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Above was my code. I thought it would have worked but it did not. it printed the ptr1 successfully but never printed the ptr2. I want to know why... Any help will be appreciated!
I am kind of new to pointer stuff, I just wanted to try my best to use the pointer in my code so that I can practice more. I know that I can totally just create two static arrays in the main part and then write the array in my function OutputEachLetter as an argument and use the pass as a reference like int &arr. However, I really want to know why is my current code wrong and why am I not allowed to use this kind of code.

Comment: what exact input and output are you feeding to/receiving from the program?

Comment: Any changes that `OutPutEachLetter` makes to `ptr` parameter are not visible to the caller. `ptr1` and `ptr2` are still null in `main`. Consider: `void f(int x) { x=42;} int y = 0; f(y); // y is still zero`

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a little effort by adding `algorithm` library plus you're using C++, take some benefits of it. Just use the `transform()` for conversion of strings into lower case, and sort them then see if they're equal or not.

Everything could  be done in a simplified way.

Consider the written program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void) {
    std::string str1, str2;

    std::cout << "Enter the first string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str1);

    std::cout << "Enter the second string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str2);

    /* --- this --- */
    transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1.begin(), ::tolower);
    transform(str2.begin(), str2.end(), str2.begin(), ::tolower);

    std::sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    std::sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());

    if (str1 == str2)
        std::cout << "Both strings are anagrams";
    else
        std::cout << "No anagrams";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, we are not allowed to use anything that we have not learned yet. which includes the algorithm library.